# JIRA JQL, how to check if all labels in a field is contained in a valid set?

Tags: jira, jql

I have a label field in JIRA called 'assets'. As labels can be manually added its easy to add a 'wrong label', thus we have a set of defined valid labels.

valid labels = (one, two, three)

The JQL I currently use is: "assets" NOT IN (one, two, three)

This works fine if ie. assets = (red, blue) etc. but if the asset fild contains one of the valid labels it does not show. ie. asset = (one, blue) is not shown, but in fact I would like it to show.

How can I create a JQL that checks that all labels in a field is contained in a set?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that with just standard JQL.

You can accomplish this using the Script Runner add-on though. It allows you to implement your own custom JQL function in Groovy using the JIRA Java API, so you can add whatever logic you desire.

Some interesting links:

- [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview)
- [Custom JQL functions](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.1-rc1/jira/custom-jql-functions.html)